# Compiling error when building Vue project after Node/dev-dependencies update

Tags: vue.js, build

I have updated Node and my dev-dependencies in my project to the latest versions. Now when I build the project, this error occurs:

```
andreas@andreas-X230:/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project$ npm run build

Error: Build failed with errors.> project@0.1.0 build
> vue-cli-service build

All browser targets in the browserslist configuration have supported ES module.
Therefore we don't build two separate bundles for differential loading.


⠙  Building for production...

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                  10:23:11

 error  in ./src/main.js

Syntax Error: Thread Loader (Worker 0)
error:0308010C:digital envelope routines::unsupported
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)


 ERROR  Error: Build failed with errors.
Error: Build failed with errors.
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/@vue/cli-service/lib/commands/build/index.js:207:23
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/webpack.js:148:8
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/HookWebpackError.js:68:3
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Cache.shutdown (/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Cache.js:150:23)
    at /opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1225:15
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:6:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.close (/opt/lampp/htdocs/homepage/apps/project/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1218:23)
```

Furthermore it looks like something is not configured properly, a there are some tabs missing in Vue UI. A similar project has tabs for `Dashboard`, `Plugins` and `Configuration`

[image]

Any idea?

Comment: Have you checked this? https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/4254

Comment: I'll check it out, thanks. Honestly I did not do anything with Vue in a while, so whatever the purpose of the different build are, I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: Furthermore setting `babel.config.js` as suggested and `npm install @vue/babel-preset-app --save-dev` did not help either.

Comment: Unfortunately I have no other ideas on this issue for the moment, I believe it is a breaking change that occurred when you update a dependency. Besides as there's no idea how old  that project is, I couldn't provide any specific suggestions on this. I personally think it is something regarding `require js` and `es module` issue but it's just a guess.